# ¿Cómo extraer props en React Class Component Next.js 12?

Tags: reactjs, class, component, next.js, props

Estoy seteando un 'state' en una función particularmente en app.js, y pasandole como Context para que ese state esté en toda la APP, ahora quisiera extraer el valor del state en un componente de tipo Class:

Esto sería en _app.js:

```
<Component
        {...pageProps}
        rol={rol}
/>
```

El state sería "rol" y este valor quisiera obtenerlo aquí:

```
class Curtain extends Component {
  static contextType = FirebaseContext;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.openMenu = this.openMenu.bind(this);
    this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
  }

  openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  }
  closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  }
  render() {
    const { usuario } = this.context;

    return(...)
  }
}

export default Curtain;
```

Comment: He borrado la publicación porque me he confundido. Lo siento

Comment: El componente al que quieres pasar props se llama Curtain o Component? Que version de next.js estas usando?

Comment: @g.4 Sí, el componente se llama "Curtain" y estoy usando la versión 12.3.1

Comment: Normalmente las props se obtienen con `this.props` y si la quireres guardar en el state, en el constructor tienes que añadir: `this.state:{rol: this.props.rol}`

Comment: @Suso estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario, pero el OP esta usando _app.js de next.js y parece que se debe configurar, sección caveats en el [punto 3 de la doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats) parece haber mas información al respecto